# I stumbled on a relationship between ln(x) and estimated probability. Can someone help me locate or generate a proof?

Tags: probability, logarithms

Yesterday, I personally stumbled on the following relationship of ln(x):

Say you have x number of checkboxes, and you randomly pick a position (p) between 1 and x. If the checkbox at position P is empty, check it. If it's already checked, do nothing. How many attempts (a) does it take to check all checkboxes.?

I found that the average number of attempts it takes to check every single checkbox appears to be equal to ln(x) * x

$$a=x \cdot ln(x)$$
$$or$$
$$a=x \cdot (ln(x) + 1)$$

I can't quite tell which. It at least seems to be very close to either after a few iterations using software. I'm assuming this is a known relationship, and was wondering if anyone can point me to a proof.

Here's an image of the observed relationship: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLjHz.png)

The X axis value, multiplied by the Y axis value determines the number of attempts found to check all of the boxes.

- The blue line indicates the code-generated coefficient to check all of the boxes
- The blue dotted line indicates the trend line for the random picks, generated by Excel
- The orange line is a perfect ln(x) of the X axis
- The green line is a perfect (ln(x) + 1) of the X axis

---

Here is the code I made to generate random results, using Excel VBA: http://pastebin.com/TYxnPDQz

- Column 1 will print the number of "checkboxes" (there's no reference of "checkboxes" in code, just using that word in this explanation)
- Column 2 will print the total number of attempts to check all "checkboxes"
- The code currently does 64 iterations.
- The number of "checkboxes" used for each iteration is equal to 2^Iter

Comment: Search up the coupon collector problem

Comment: @OwainWest Thanks for posting the name of that, I am glad to know it.

Comment: It seems that you have discovered entropy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory) It is a measure for disorder in a system.

Comment: Nice discovery! (Even if others have discovered it before you...)

Comment: @Kagaratsch : It is not clear to me how the coupon collector problem relates to the link you give on entropy (other than they both use probabilty and logarithms).  Did you have something particular in mind?

Comment: @Michael The quantity $x \ln x$ is the information theoretic entropy (or also Gibbs entropy), but I guess this is just a coincidence here. (Unless there is something like counting of information density in the space of squares going on here... don't want to make any claims.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact expectation for any $x$ is 
$$E_x = x H_x = x \sum_{n=1}^x \frac1n$$

$H_x$ is called the $x$-th harmonic number.

Your expressions are both wrong, but really close; the reality lies between them: For large $x$,

$$E_x = x ((\ln x )+ \gamma) + \frac12 - \frac1{12x} + \frac1{120x^3}+ O\left( \frac1{x^5}\right)$$

where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant, which is about $0.58$.  Pretty much between 0 and 1.

Comment: I added brackets in the last equation  for clarity: $(\ln x)+\gamma $ rather than $\ln x+\gamma$